# Lower bound on smallest eigenvalue of a large matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, upper-lower-bounds

I have a matrix, say $A$, which is square of dimension $n$ and symmetric by construction. The dimension $n$ is large, i.e. it is allowed to pass to infinity.

I can show that, for every $n$-dimensional vector $b$ which is bounded in $L_{1}$-norm, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|b_{i}| < \infty$, we have that

$b'Ab>0$,

so in this sense $A$ is positive definite.

Can I say anything about the smallest eigenvalue of $A$ with this information? All I would want to know is whether the smallest eigenvalue is positive, I do not need any "sophisticated"/sharp bounds.

Comment: The way you phrased it, you don't have much. The $n\times n$ matrix $A=\mathrm{diag}(\frac1n, \frac1n, \ldots, \frac1n)$ satisfies all your assumptions, but the smallest eigenvalue tends to $0$ as $n\to \infty$. In particular, the fact that $\sum_1^n |b_i|<\infty$ is an empty condition. All finite sums are finite.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $A$, then it has an eigenvector $b$. So $Ab = \lambda b$ and $b'Ab = \lambda b'b$. Since both $b'Ab > 0$ (as Giuseppi Negro pointed out, your $L^1$ condition holds for all $b$) and $b'b > 0$, it must be that $\lambda > 0$.